# Is there a way to view poller information in the decider or activity workflow worker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

How would I know that my application (WorkflowHost, ActivityHost) which represents a workflow / task is polling SWF. Is there a way to instrument the application to view this information?

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/worker/DecisionTaskPoller.html

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/worker/ActivityTaskPoller.html